# THC Hydra sends GET request without parameter before actual request with parameter which causes authentication problems

Tags: http, brute-force, password-cracking, api, hydra

I am using THC Hydra (v9.0) on GNU/Linux to pentest my private API.

The GET route in question requires a key as GET parameter which returns an auth token if the correct key was submitted else "false".
If no key or a wrong key is submitted, the route returns always "false" for the next 5 seconds, even if the correct key is submitted.

*(Please do not comment the way the API works, this is not the question)*

**Problem:**
Even when providing the correct key to Hydra, it returns "false".
When executing Hydra with `-d` it shows me that before the actual request with the key as parameter is sent, it sends a request without any parameters.

**Question:**
Why does Hydra do this and can I prevent it?

This cannot be due to the HTTP request because with other tools like curl or Postman, it immediately sends the request with the parameter.

Comment: See [this post](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/issues/514#issuecomment-796727505).

Comment: There appears to be an option to disable that function in `hydra-http-form.c` (`(g|G)=              skip pre-requests - only use this when no pre-cookies are required`). If that's the module you're using you may have luck with that option.

Comment: @user Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @MechMK1 I do not have THC Hydra, so I don't know if that even answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @user said in the comments, Hydra does this pre request to get the inital cookies of the webpage.

You can set another webpage for the pre-request with `c=` as optional parameter after the check condition like so:
`hydra -l user -p pass 127.0.0.1 http-get-form "/api/route/:password=^PASS^:false:c="`

This way hydra does not use the actual route to fetch the cookies and my problem is solved.